# APNS connection failure

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Facing problem with APNS push services at client end. Server side is ok and it sends push to APNS properly as particular devices get stuck at some moment. Here are the server logs.

VOIP Push: Push notification waiting by APNs gateway.

VOIP Push: Push notification accepted by APNs gateway.

**Here are the console logs of effected device**

```
    default 09:16:30.203262 +0400   apsd    Connection 1507: enabling TLS
    default 09:16:30.203409 +0400   apsd    Connection 1507: starting, TC(0x0)
    default 09:16:30.203504 +0400   apsd    [C1507 DBE7C1B4-DC94-4B2A-BD21-63661595E267 Hostname#45fde594:443 tcp, url hash: f51ce5f3, tls] start
    default 09:16:30.204664 +0400   apsd    nw_connection_report_state_with_handler_on_nw_queue [C1507] reporting state preparing
    default 09:16:30.205294 +0400   mDNSResponder   [R80990] DNSServiceCreateConnection START PID[99](apsd)
    default 09:16:30.205592 +0400   mDNSResponder   [R80991] DNSServiceGetAddrInfo(C000D000, 0, 0, ) START PID[99](apsd)
    default 09:16:30.206815 +0400   apsd    Task . setting up Connection 1507
    default 09:16:30.208190 +0400   apsd    nw_connection_report_state_with_handler_on_nw_queue [C1507] reporting state failed error DNS Error: NoSuchRecord
    error   09:16:30.208282 +0400   apsd    Connection 1507: received failure notification
    error   09:16:30.208361 +0400   apsd    Connection 1507: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
    error   09:16:30.208448 +0400   apsd    Connection 1507: encountered error(12:8)
    default 09:16:30.208522 +0400   apsd    Connection 1507: is being canceled
    default 09:16:30.208600 +0400   mDNSResponder   [R80990] DNSServiceCreateConnection STOP PID[99](apsd)
    default 09:16:30.208678 +0400   mDNSResponder   [R80991] DNSServiceGetAddrInfo() STOP PID[99](apsd)
    default 09:16:30.208848 +0400   apsd    Connection 1507: summary for unused connection {protocol="(null)", domain_lookup_duration_ms=0, connect_duration_ms=0, secure_connection_duration_ms=0, idle_duration_ms=0}
    default 09:16:30.208932 +0400   apsd    [C1507 DBE7C1B4-DC94-4B2A-BD21-63661595E267 Hostname#45fde594:443 tcp, url hash: f51ce5f3, tls] cancel
    default 09:16:30.209009 +0400   apsd    [C1507 Hostname#45fde594:443 tcp, url hash: f51ce5f3, tls] cancelled
    default 09:16:30.209091 +0400   apsd    0.000s [C1507 29735B49-F0FB-40A5-A092-F15E19D8B4B0 Hostname#45fde594:443 resolver path=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns] path:start
    default 09:16:30.209174 +0400   apsd    0.000s [C1507 29735B49-F0FB-40A5-A092-F15E19D8B4B0 Hostname#45fde594:443 resolver path=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns] path:satisfied
    default 09:16:30.209260 +0400   apsd    0.001s [C1507 29735B49-F0FB-40A5-A092-F15E19D8B4B0 Hostname#45fde594:443 resolver path=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns] resolver:start_dns
    default 09:16:30.209341 +0400   apsd    0.003s [C1507 29735B49-F0FB-40A5-A092-F15E19D8B4B0 Hostname#45fde594:443 resolver path=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns] path:trigger
    default 09:16:30.209427 +0400   apsd    0.004s [C1507 29735B49-F0FB-40A5-A092-F15E19D8B4B0 Hostname#45fde594:443 resolver path=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns] resolver:receive_dns DNS Error: NoSuchRecord
    default 09:16:30.209509 +0400   apsd    0.005s [C1507] path:cancel
    default 09:16:30.209821 +0400   apsd    nw_connection_report_state_with_handler_on_nw_queue [C1507] reporting state cancelled error DNS Error: NoSuchRecord
    default 09:16:30.209998 +0400   apsd    Task . can retry(N) with reason(2) for error [12:8]
    default 09:16:30.211029 +0400   apsd    _CFNetworkIsConnectedToInternet returning 1, flagsValid: 1, flags: 0x2
    error   09:16:30.211367 +0400   apsd    Task . HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])
    default 09:16:30.211510 +0400   apsd    Task . summary for task failure {transaction_duration_ms=9, response_status=0, cache_hit=0}
    default 09:16:30.211758 +0400   apsd    removing all entries config 0x100f3bfc0
    default 09:16:30.212028 +0400   apsd    removing all entries config 0x100f3bfc0
    default 09:16:30.212151 +0400   apsd     Calling configuration completion blocks, expiration date Thu Dec 12 09:31:30 2019 error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x102121bc0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.}
    default 09:16:30.212393 +0400   apsd    APSTCPStream  got config   -- opened? YES
    default 09:16:30.212593 +0400   apsd    Failed to load config bag: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x102121bc0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.}
    default 09:16:30.212700 +0400   apsd    Using DNS TXT record lookup to determine load balance count for development
    default 09:16:30.212786 +0400   apsd     performing DNS lookup for 
    default 09:16:30.213329 +0400   mDNSResponder   [R80992] DNSServiceQueryRecord(0, 0, , TXT) START PID[99](apsd)
    default 09:16:30.214890 +0400   apsd    Closing  with environment [development]
    default 09:16:30.215049 +0400   mDNSResponder   [R80992] DNSServiceQueryRecord(0, 0, , TXT) STOP PID[99](apsd)
    default 09:16:30.215730 +0400   apsd    : Stream error occurred for  onInterface NonCellular: Error Domain=APSErrorDomain Code=1 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=}
    default 09:16:30.215855 +0400   apsd    : Calling into AWD for ConnectionDisconnected (withError)
    default 09:16:30.217664 +0400   apsd    : AWD for ConnectionDisconnected (withError) finished
    default 09:16:30.217741 +0400   apsd     _disconnectStream for interface: NonCellular
    default 09:16:30.217821 +0400   apsd     asked to change isSuspended=NO to NO
    default 09:16:30.217896 +0400   apsd    Closing  with environment [development]
    default 09:16:30.217972 +0400   apsd    : enableNonCellularConnections changed to NO
    default 09:16:30.218458 +0400   apsd    Connection closed development NonCellular
    default 09:16:30.218633 +0400   apsd     canUseProxy? NO deviceConfiguration NO  isNearby NO
    default 09:16:30.218706 +0400   apsd     received courierConnectionStatusDidChange from .
    default 09:16:30.218877 +0400   apsd     canUseProxy? NO deviceConfiguration NO  isNearby NO
    default 09:16:30.219036 +0400   apsd     canUseProxy? NO deviceConfiguration NO  isNearby NO
    default 09:16:30.219115 +0400   apsd     updating network guidance isConnected? YES
    default 09:16:30.219271 +0400   apsd     canUseProxy? NO deviceConfiguration NO  isNearby NO
    default 09:16:30.219404 +0400   apsd     canUseProxy? NO deviceConfiguration NO  isNearby NO
    default 09:16:30.219532 +0400   apsd    : Disconnected in response to connection failure on interface NonCellular. (Consecutive failures: 24) isConnected NO onInterface None  shouldUseDualChannel YES. Connected on 0 interfaces.
    default 09:16:30.219596 +0400   apsd    Created metric container: 0x130002 succeeded? YES
    default 09:16:30.220000 +0400   apsd     Connection method alternative changed to 1
    default 09:16:30.220094 +0400   apsd    Advising client to enter reconnect mode in response to a connection failure since currently in reconnect mode
    default 09:16:30.220166 +0400   apsd    Resuming push keep alive timer in normal mode with action PCActionShrinkPushKeepAliveInterval
    default 09:16:30.220230 +0400   apsd    Last timer interruption was early: []. Expected fire time was [].
    default 09:16:30.220300 +0400   apsd    WiFi growth algorithm-IPv4: received action PCActionShrinkPushKeepAliveInterval while in stage Backoff
    default 09:16:30.220366 +0400   apsd    {keep alive interval = 600, state = Backoff, next recalibration date = (null)}: adjustGrowthAlgorithmMode. {lastMode: Defaults, currentMode: Defaults}
    default 09:16:30.220431 +0400   apsd     created 
    default 09:16:30.220506 +0400   apsd    Started simple timer  with fire date [2019-12-12 09:27:05 +0400]
    default 09:16:30.220713 +0400   apsd     created preventSleepTimer  and fireTimer  on queue 
    default 09:16:30.221159 +0400   apsd    Enabling power monitoring for  - 6 timers
    default 09:16:30.221275 +0400   apsd     Existing wake at (null) re-scheduling to 2019-12-12 09:26:50 +0400 with leeway of 0
    default 09:16:30.221551 +0400   apsd    Request to schedule wake 1 date 2019-12-12 09:26:50 +0400 leeway 0 service identifier com.apple.apsd(sandbox.push.apple.com)-NonCellular unique identifier 
    default 09:16:30.221693 +0400   apsd     calculating _earlyFireDate. powerStateDetectionSupported = NO = (detectionSupported(YES) && (wwanIsUp(NO) || ! internetReachable(YES)))
    default 09:16:30.221779 +0400   apsd    Last system wake date (2019-12-12 09:11:10 +0400) was longer than half of the timer duration, so setting minimum fire date to fire date.
    default 09:16:30.221867 +0400   apsd     Device is plugged in, overriding earlyFireProportion to be 1.0
    default 09:16:30.222061 +0400   apsd     Calculated minimum fire date [2019-12-12 09:27:05 +0400] (100%) with fire date [2019-12-12 09:27:05 +0400], start date [2019-12-12 09:16:30 +0400], minimum early fire proportion 0, power state detection supported: no, in high power state: no, early fire constant interval 0.000000
    default 09:16:30.222194 +0400   apsd    PCConnectionManager was stopped by client
    default 09:16:30.222261 +0400   apsd    Invalidating timer 
    default 09:16:30.222322 +0400   apsd    Invalidating simple timer 
    default 09:16:30.222699 +0400   apsd    Scheduling a wake for date  leeway 0 wake identifier 
    default 09:16:30.224084 +0400   apsd    Wake schedule for ''() completed for [] (took 0.002 seconds; result code 0)
    default 09:16:30.225070 +0400   apsd    Canceling system wake for simpletimer [2019-12-12 09:26:50 +0400]
    default 09:16:30.225159 +0400   apsd    Request to schedule wake 0 date 2019-12-12 09:26:50 +0400 leeway 0 service identifier com.apple.apsd(sandbox.push.apple.com)-NonCellular unique identifier 
    default 09:16:30.225385 +0400   apsd    APSCourier  adjusting connection. Connected on 0 interfaces. Current link quality: 
    default 09:16:30.225498 +0400   apsd    Disabling power monitoring for  - 5 timers
    default 09:16:30.225646 +0400   apsd     canUseProxy? NO deviceConfiguration NO  isNearby NO
    default 09:16:30.225720 +0400   apsd     calling _connectStream with interface preference NonCellular
    default 09:16:30.225800 +0400   apsd     attempting to _connectStream. currently onInterface None consecutiveFailures 24 preference NonCellular shouldUseDualChannel YES. Connected on 0 interfaces.
    default 09:16:30.225869 +0400   apsd    _getClientIdentity: already had identity: 
    default 09:16:30.225929 +0400   apsd     _connectStream - Stopping the connectionManager on our attemptInterface NonCellular
    default 09:16:30.225990 +0400   apsd    PCConnectionManager was stopped by client
    default 09:16:30.226047 +0400   apsd    : isWWANUsable NO  isWiFiUsable YES onInterface NonCellular
    default 09:16:30.226112 +0400   apsd    : enableNonCellularConnections changed to YES
    default 09:16:30.226165 +0400   apsd     Opening stream on interface NonCellular
    default 09:16:30.226214 +0400   apsd    Cancelling scheduled wake for  wake identifier 
    default 09:16:30.226560 +0400   apsd    Opening  with environment [development]
    default 09:16:30.226659 +0400   apsd    loadConfigurationForEnvironment:  development interface: NonCellular
    default 09:16:30.227135 +0400   apsd    Task . resuming, QOS(0x15) Voucher (null)
    default 09:16:30.227218 +0400   apsd    Wake cancel for ''() completed for [] (took 0.002 seconds; result code 0)
    default 09:16:30.227330 +0400   apsd    Opening stream onInterface: NonCellular, development
    default 09:16:30.227496 +0400   apsd    : Connecting courier stream using configuration bag at  and port TCP 443
    default 09:16:30.227752 +0400   apsd    Closing  with environment [development]
    default 09:16:30.227837 +0400   apsd    Task . {strength 0, tls 4, ct 0, sub 0, sig 1, ciphers 0, bundle 1, builtin 0}
    default 09:16:30.228815 +0400   apsd    Connection 1508: enabling TLS
    default 09:16:30.228964 +0400   apsd    Connection 1508: starting, TC(0x0)
    default 09:16:30.229353 +0400   apsd    [C1508 F67A490F-3214-41AE-AC96-0CD52FC88397 Hostname#45fde594:443 tcp, url hash: f51ce5f3, tls] start
    default 09:16:30.230101 +0400   symptomsd   NBSM: received symptom that apsd is failing on WiFi in state: idle
    default 09:16:30.231119 +0400   apsd    nw_connection_report_state_with_handler_on_nw_queue [C1508] reporting state preparing
    default 09:16:30.231365 +0400   mDNSResponder   [R80993] DNSServiceCreateConnection START PID[99](apsd)
    default 09:16:30.231620 +0400   mDNSResponder   [R80994] DNSServiceGetAddrInfo(C000D000, 0, 0, ) START PID[99](apsd)
    default 09:16:30.232216 +0400   apsd    Task . setting up Connection 1508
    default 09:16:30.233279 +0400   mDNSResponder   [R80993] DNSServiceCreateConnection STOP PID[99](apsd)
    default 09:16:30.233462 +0400   mDNSResponder   [R80994] DNSServiceGetAddrInfo() STOP PID[99](apsd)
    default 09:16:30.233983 +0400   apsd    nw_connection_report_state_with_handler_on_nw_queue [C1508] reporting state failed error DNS Error: NoSuchRecord
    error   09:16:30.234066 +0400   apsd    Connection 1508: received failure notification
    error   09:16:30.234124 +0400   apsd    Connection 1508: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
    error   09:16:30.234179 +0400   apsd    Connection 1508: encountered error(12:8)
    default 09:16:30.234443 +0400   apsd    Connection 1508: is being canceled
    default 09:16:30.234525 +0400   apsd    Connection 1508: summary for unused connection {protocol="(null)", domain_lookup_duration_ms=0, connect_duration_ms=0, secure_connection_duration_ms=0, idle_duration_ms=0}
    default 09:16:30.234584 +0400   apsd    [C1508 F67A490F-3214-41AE-AC96-0CD52FC88397 Hostname#45fde594:443 tcp, url hash: f51ce5f3, tls] cancel
    default 09:16:30.234681 +0400   apsd    [C1508 Hostname#45fde594:443 tcp, url hash: f51ce5f3, tls] cancelled
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar situation where no push was arriving, and  dns errors were logged when querying sandox.push.apple.com

A fix was to change the phones to use an alternative DNS like Google (8.8.8.8) or Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) in the wifi settings.